# Hidden data in user profile in laravel app

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and I want to build app. When you want to see another user informations you have to ask him if you can see. If he click yes you can, if not - no. I have currently this:

User model:

```
public function SharedDatas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SharedData');
}

public function getUserById($id)
{
    $user = User::with('user_data','SharedDatas')->where('id', $id)->first();

    return $user;
}
```

SharedData controller:

```
public function checkIfShared($request)
    {
        $shared = SharedData::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])->where('shared_to', $request['user_to_share_id'])->first();

        return $shared;
    }

    public function shareData($request) 
    {
        $SharedData = new SharedData;

        $SharedData->user_id = $request['user_id'];
        $SharedData->shared_to = $request['user_to_share_id'];

        $SharedData->save();    

        $SharedData = new SharedData;

        $SharedData->user_id = $request['user_to_share_id'];
        $SharedData->shared_to = $request['user_id']; 

        $SharedData->save();    
    }
```

But how to display or hide data in blade? View should know about user id and another user id to share. Now it works only with user with id 1 and 2, when is id 3 it isn't work. How can I reach this?

Comment: How are you displaying the data right now?

Comment: Sth like $user[shared_datas][0] but it shows relationshil between id 1 and 2, not 3 as I want

Answer (score 0):

hiding this data is a bad idea!

best way to do such jobs is using javascript. with javascript you can send data to user dynamically.

of course you can do that with php. create a table for users messages. whenever user granted access should receive a message. so save the message in db. put a link for message box in the site and show the user message there. put another user data or (better) link to that data in a message.